# Excel formula to change one cell value to another value based on a third cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

to make this simple a1 has a value that can change, b1 has the formula to test a1 value. c1 is reset to a chosen value based on a1.

I have a table that people can input values. I have a list box in a1 which they can choose 'reset'. I want the table values to change to 0 , to 'clear' the table so people can then input new values.

I was trying to test this with a single cell as stated as above. The formula I put into b1

```
=if(a1="RESET",(c1=0),c1)
```

this isn't changing c1 value but is including the c1=0 into the test part of the if then.

trouble is we are not allowed to use Macros or vb code because where this is stored so I am forced to use formulas.

was this clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

A formula can't change another target. You'll need two formulas

B1 - `=IF(A1="RESET",1,0)`

C1 - `=IF(B1>0,"woohoo",0)`

If the point of the exercise is to have only one formula in B1 because users can alter C1 to remove the formula, this isn't possible.

Comment: I assumed the if statement in B1 is always executed before the if statement in C1.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it isn't clear what cell is supposed to be dependent on the other, but if I understand the requirements correctly, what you want to do can't be done without VBA or an extra manual step.

As Raystafarian describes, you can't change one cell with a formula in a different cell.  However, a cell also can't have both a formula and a value.  If you have a formula in B1 or C1 and then enter a value there, the formula is lost, so that would work only one time.

Your formula implies that you want the input to go into C1 because that's what's displayed in B1, and A1 changes the value displayed in B1 to `0` when A1="RESET".  Without VBA, I think the closest you can get to what you describe would be something like this:

- Enter new values in C1, replacing what was there before.
- B1 could contain: `=IF(A1="RESET",0,C1)`.

That accomplishes what your formula describes.  B1 would serve as the display location in the table, and indicator that a new value is required, but the value would go in C1.

Unless A1 changes, however, it will continue to contain `RESET`, so changing the value in C1 won't make B1 display the new value.  A1 would also need to change, but this requirement would create a circular reference without VBA or manual intervention.  You need something that detects the entry of the new value and triggers a change in A1.  That type of action requires VBA, or the user making a manual change to A1 after the new value is ready to be displayed in B1.